# Self-referential struct , containing three pointers (called left, right and parent)

Tags: c, linux

I've this question in my assignment and have no clue about it if anyone could help me with it

I need to create a self-referential struct , containing three pointers (called left, right and
parent) to other instances of the same struct, as well as a pointer to a 1d
array , the type of which can change.

```
    struct node { 
        int* left; 
        int* right;
        int* parent;
        struct node* link; 
    }; 

    int main() 
    { 
        struct node ob; 
        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: Whats the question here?

Comment: Thats the requirement that I need to create a self-referential struct , containing three pointers (called left, right and parent) to other instances of the same struct, as well as a pointer to a 1d array , the type of which can change.
.. I've coded something but I don't know if its right@PowerStat

Comment: It's not right, becaise your left, right and parent point to an int and not to the struct itself. Also your 1 dimensional array pointer is mising.

Comment: Can I get a correction here? Im a noob student i know @PowerStat

Comment: I think you should better do it yourself for learning.

Comment: struct* node { 
        int array [];
        int left; 
        int right;
        int parent;
        struct node* link; 
    }; 

    int main() 
    { 
        struct node ob; 
        return 0; 
    }

Is it better? @PowerStat

Comment: The instructions say that `left` should be a pointer to the same type of struct. How can `int left` possibly be correct?

Comment: What you've written is a linked list, because the `link` member is a pointer to the same type. What the assignment is asking for is similar, but there should be three pointers named `left`, `right`, and `parent`.

Comment: In what you posted, I see a `link` that could reference the "parent node", but the remaining pointers are all *integer* pointer and cannot point to type `struct node` without violating the *strict-aliasing rule* [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6). If you have one integer array, the remaining pointers should be type `struct node *` if you have a tree structure with a parent reference.

Answer (score 1):

> containing three pointers (called left, right and parent) to other instances of the same struct,

This requirement would lead to:

```
    struct node { 
        struct node * left; 
        struct node * right;
        struct node * parent;
```

> as well as a pointer to a 1d array , the type of which can change.

And this may be done using a `void*`:

```
        void * data;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are still stuck, then to help point you in the right direction, the data structure you are dealing will closely resembles a *binary-tree*. The giveaway is the `left` and `right` pointers which will point to other nodes in the tree. The only addition you add is a `parent` pointer which you presumably want to point back at the node above the current in the tree -- which would allow iteration from the current node back to the root node of the tree along any path within the tree.

If that is the case, the basic structure you need is:

```
typedef struct node { 
    struct node* left; 
    struct node* right;
    struct node* parent;
    int *data; 
} node;
```

(**note:** a `typedef` was added to allow the use of `node` as a type rather than always having to type `struct node`)

What you do with the structure is up to you, but logically it would be used similar to a *binary-tree* with the only additions being to assign the node for the previous level in the tree as the `parent` node in each leaf. A basic function to create each node (with only minimal error reporting) could be:

```
void *create_node (int *data)
{
    node *p = malloc (sizeof *p);

    if (!p) {
        perror ("malloc-create_node");
        return NULL;
    }

    p->data = data ? data : NULL;
    p->left = NULL;
    p->right = NULL;
    p->parent = NULL;

    return p;
}
```

(**note:** `data` can be the address of an integer array or `NULL`, either of which will be assigned to the `data` pointer for the node)

The insert function for adding node would be a normal btree insert with the addition of assigning the `parent` node pointer the address of the node immediately above it in the tree, e.g.

```
void insert (node *tree, int *data)
{
    if (!tree->data)
        tree->data = data;
    else if (data && *data <= *tree->data) {
        if (!tree->left) {
            tree->left = create_node (data);
            tree->left->parent = tree->left;
        }
        else
            insert (tree->left, data);
    }
    else if (data && *data > *tree->data) {
        if (!tree->right) {
            tree->right = create_node (data);
            tree->right->parent = tree->right;
        }
        else
            insert (tree->right, data);
    }
}
```

Adding your *preorder, inorder* and *postorder* traversals, and a function to free the memory allocated to the tree, along with a short example program that outputs the pointer address for each node could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node { 
    struct node* left; 
    struct node* right;
    struct node* parent;
    int *data; 
} node;

void *create_node (int *data)
{
    node *p = malloc (sizeof *p);

    if (!p) {
        perror ("malloc-create_node");
        return NULL;
    }

    p->data = data ? data : NULL;
    p->left = NULL;
    p->right = NULL;
    p->parent = NULL;

    return p;
}

void insert (node *tree, int *data)
{
    if (!tree->data)
        tree->data = data;
    else if (data && *data <= *tree->data) {
        if (!tree->left) {
            tree->left = create_node (data);
            tree->left->parent = tree->left;
        }
        else
            insert (tree->left, data);
    }
    else if (data && *data > *tree->data) {
        if (!tree->right) {
            tree->right = create_node (data);
            tree->right->parent = tree->right;
        }
        else
            insert (tree->right, data);
    }
}

void preorder (node *tree)
{
    if (tree) {
        printf ("%10p  %10p  %10p  ->  %p   {%d, %d}\n", 
                (void*)tree->left, (void*)tree->parent, (void*)tree->right,
                (void*)tree->data, tree->data[0], tree->data[1]);
        preorder (tree->left);
        preorder (tree->right);
    }
}

void inorder (node *tree)
{
    if (tree) {
        inorder (tree->left);
        printf ("%10p  %10p  %10p  ->  %p   {%d, %d}\n", 
                (void*)tree->left, (void*)tree->parent, (void*)tree->right,
                (void*)tree->data, tree->data[0], tree->data[1]);
        inorder (tree->right);
    }
}

void postorder (node *tree)
{
    if (tree) {
        postorder (tree->left);
        postorder (tree->right);
        printf ("%10p  %10p  %10p  ->  %p   {%d, %d}\n", 
                (void*)tree->left, (void*)tree->parent, (void*)tree->right,
                (void*)tree->data, tree->data[0], tree->data[1]);
    }
}

void freetree (node *tree)
{
    if (tree) {
        if (tree->left)
            freetree (tree->left);
        if (tree->right)
            freetree (tree->right);
        free (tree);
    }
}

int main(void) {

    int array[][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}},
        n = sizeof array / sizeof *array;
    struct node *ob = create_node (NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        insert (ob, array[i]);

    puts ("\n    left       parent       right          data\n"
          "---------------------------------------------------------------\n"
          "preorder:\n");
    preorder (ob);
    puts ("\ninorder:\n");
    inorder (ob);
    puts ("\npostorder:\n");
    postorder (ob);

    freetree (ob);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/treelrp

    left       parent       right          data
---------------------------------------------------------------
preorder:

     (nil)       (nil)    0xad2040  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68a0   {1, 2}
  0xad20a0    0xad2040    0xad2070  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68a8   {3, 4}
     (nil)    0xad20a0       (nil)  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68b8   {2, 4}
  0xad20d0    0xad2070       (nil)  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68b0   {5, 6}
     (nil)    0xad20d0       (nil)  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68c0   {4, 5}

inorder:

     (nil)       (nil)    0xad2040  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68a0   {1, 2}
     (nil)    0xad20a0       (nil)  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68b8   {2, 4}
  0xad20a0    0xad2040    0xad2070  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68a8   {3, 4}
     (nil)    0xad20d0       (nil)  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68c0   {4, 5}
  0xad20d0    0xad2070       (nil)  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68b0   {5, 6}

postorder:

     (nil)    0xad20a0       (nil)  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68b8   {2, 4}
     (nil)    0xad20d0       (nil)  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68c0   {4, 5}
  0xad20d0    0xad2070       (nil)  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68b0   {5, 6}
  0xad20a0    0xad2040    0xad2070  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68a8   {3, 4}
     (nil)       (nil)    0xad2040  ->  0x7ffc0dbd68a0   {1, 2}
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/treelrp
==24386== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==24386== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24386== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==24386== Command: ./bin/treelrp
==24386==

    left       parent       right          data
---------------------------------------------------------------
preorder:

     (nil)       (nil)   0x51db0a0  ->  0xffefffc00   {1, 2}
 0x51db160   0x51db0a0   0x51db100  ->  0xffefffc08   {3, 4}
     (nil)   0x51db160       (nil)  ->  0xffefffc18   {2, 4}
 0x51db1c0   0x51db100       (nil)  ->  0xffefffc10   {5, 6}
     (nil)   0x51db1c0       (nil)  ->  0xffefffc20   {4, 5}

inorder:

     (nil)       (nil)   0x51db0a0  ->  0xffefffc00   {1, 2}
     (nil)   0x51db160       (nil)  ->  0xffefffc18   {2, 4}
 0x51db160   0x51db0a0   0x51db100  ->  0xffefffc08   {3, 4}
     (nil)   0x51db1c0       (nil)  ->  0xffefffc20   {4, 5}
 0x51db1c0   0x51db100       (nil)  ->  0xffefffc10   {5, 6}

postorder:

     (nil)   0x51db160       (nil)  ->  0xffefffc18   {2, 4}
     (nil)   0x51db1c0       (nil)  ->  0xffefffc20   {4, 5}
 0x51db1c0   0x51db100       (nil)  ->  0xffefffc10   {5, 6}
 0x51db160   0x51db0a0   0x51db100  ->  0xffefffc08   {3, 4}
     (nil)       (nil)   0x51db0a0  ->  0xffefffc00   {1, 2}
==24386==
==24386== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24386==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24386==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 160 bytes allocated
==24386==
==24386== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==24386==
==24386== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==24386== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Your implementation needs may be a bit different, but the basics will be similar. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Please what is the idea behind this: `p->data = data ? data : NULL;` complicated thingy?

Comment: @alk Oh sorry, that is more a comment that `create_node` allows data to either be passed and set when it is called, or passed as NULL and set on `insert`. I should probably have commented the entire thing, but I was fighting sleep when I posted it :)

Answer (score -1):

```
struct node
{
    void *left;
    void *right;
    void *parent;
    struct node *link;
}
```

I think you should use void pointer. But you should know what this pointer mean. It may represent a 1d array or an struct.

Comment: I was also thinking `void*`. From what I understand in the op's question, the pointers need to point to the structure itself. Three pointers, so they'd be of type `struct node` and not `void*`. Although `void*` can also point to `node`. For the part where the type can change, I think that's where we would need a `void*`.

Comment: The only problem with `void*` is you will end up needing to cast before you can reference anything other than the pointer itself. So, e.g., `right->parent` would need to be cast which limits the usefulness of simply making them `void*`.